# Modal con Bootstrap llama a link en PHP desde MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Buenas, quería consultar lo siguiente:

Al generar un `modal` con Bootstrap y llamando desde la base de datos me genera el `modal` pero por más que haya muchos datos, siempre me muestra el primero que toma.

A continuación código en `PHP`:

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT `video`,`info` FROM `tutorial` group by `video`,`info` ", $link);

<button type=button  class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal>Open Modal</button>
                            <div id=myModal class=modal fade role=dialog>
                                <div class=modal-dialog>
                                    <div class=modal-content>
                                        <div class=modal-header>
                            <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
                                <h4 class=modal-title>Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class=modal-body>
                                <p><a href=' . $row[1] . '>$row[1]</a></p>      
                            </div>
                            <div class=modal-footer>
                                <button type=button class=btn btn-default data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>";
```

EDITADO: Adjunto el código completo: Lo que pretendo es que por cada dato en la base, aparecerá un botón que abrirá un modal y ahí estará la dirección del video de ese dato.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Hola!</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                include("conexion.php");
                $link = Conectarse();

                $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT `video`FROM `tutorial` group by  `video`", $link);
                echo '<table background="id="grid-selection" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">';
                // Establish the output variable
                echo ' <thead><tr class=info>';
                echo '<th data-column-id="video" style=text-align:center>Video</th>';

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($consulta)) {
                    echo "<tr>";  
                    if($row[0]<> NULL){
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo"<button type=button  class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal>Open Modal</button>
                            <div id=myModal class=modal fade role=dialog>
                                <div class=modal-dialog>
                                    <div class=modal-content>
                                        <div class=modal-header>
                            <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
                                <h4 class=modal-title>Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class=modal-body>
                                    <p><a href=' . $row[0] . '>$row[0]</a></p>      
                                    <div class=modal-footer>
                                <button type=button class=btn btn-default data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>";
                        echo"</td>";
                            }else{
                        echo "<td style=text-align:center>$row[0]</td>";
                    }
                }  
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "</table>";?>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La parte de código que se incluye en esta pregunta está incompleta y no es suficiente para saber qué es lo que falla. Por favor, añade más código para ver cómo se hace la consulta completa (no sólo el SELECT) y cómo se escriben todos los datos en la página

Comment: por favor agrega un ejemplo de los datos que quieres mostrar en la vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo hago eso por medio de Id's, por ejemplo:

**EDITADO**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Hola!</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                include("conexion.php");
                $link = Conectarse();

                $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT `video`FROM `tutorial` group by  `video`", $link);
                echo '<table background="id="grid-selection" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">';
                // Establish the output variable
                echo ' <thead><tr class=info>';
                echo '<th data-column-id="video" style=text-align:center>Video</th>';
                $contador = 1;
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($consulta)) {
                    echo "<tr>";  
                    if($row[0]<> NULL){
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo"<button type=button  class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal".$contador.">Open Modal</button>
                            <div id=myModal".$contador." class=modal fade role=dialog>
                                <div class=modal-dialog>
                                    <div class=modal-content>
                                        <div class=modal-header>
                            <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
                                <h4 class=modal-title>Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class=modal-body>
                                    <p><a href=' . $row[0] . '>$row[0]</a></p>      
                                    <div class=modal-footer>
                                <button type=button class=btn btn-default data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>";
                        echo"</td>";
                        $contador++;
                            }else{
                        echo "<td style=text-align:center>$row[0]</td>";
                    }
                }  
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "</table>";?>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se le agrego un contador (No veo en tu select un **id** "**SIEMPRE EN UNA TABLA LA PRIMERA COLUMNA DEBE SER UN IDENTIFICADOR**"), ese contador va en en el id del botón y del modal y antes de que el while haga su iteración aumentamos el contador +1.

Comment: No puedo comentar en tu pregunta por mi reputación. La solución es agregandoles **id's** como comento en mi respuesta, agregale un id al botón y ese mismo id va en el modal, lógico para referenciar cada botón para su modal. Edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

tu pregunta es poco clara, voy a suponer que el problema radica en que no se muestran todos los datos que retorna la consulta. también voy a suponer que los datos que provienen de la consulta se encuentran en row.

```
<button type=button  class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal>Open Modal</button>
                        <div id=myModal class=modal fade role=dialog>
                            <div class=modal-dialog>
                                <div class=modal-content>
                                    <div class=modal-header>
                        <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal>&times;</button>
                            <h4 class=modal-title>Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class=modal-body>
                            <p>
                             <?php foreach($consulta => $row){ ?>
                                  <a href=' . $row[1] . '>$row[1]</a>
                             <?php } ?>
                            </p>      
                        </div>
                        <div class=modal-footer>
                            <button type=button class=btn btn-default data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
```